# About state function

Tags: thermodynamics

As I undersand in thermodynamics, a gas with an equation of state $f(V,T,p)=0$ will need only 2 variables (e.g $V$ and $p$) to determine its state.

Regarding this question:

[I still don't understand how a gas with an equation of state f(T,p,V)=0 can change if 2 state functions are fixed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/125938/i-still-dont-understand-how-a-gas-with-an-equation-of-state-ft-p-v-0-can-chan)

if we fix the entropy $S$ and the volume $V$, the state of gas can still change. Why is that possible? If $f(T,p)_V=0$ and $S(T,p)_V=S$ fixed, then is it not true that the state of gas is fixed?

I know I'm wrong somewhere, please correct me.

Comment: You seem to be neglecting particle number.

Comment: let consider a bulk if gas only

Answer (score 0):

You write

> if we fix the entropy $S$ and the volume $V$, the state of the gas can still change.

For a fixed number $N$ of particles, this is not true.  A given $S$, $V$, and $N$ will fix $T$ according to the Sackur-Tetrode equation for the entropy of the gas, and then the ideal gas law fixes the pressure $p$ as well, so everything becomes fixed.

Comment: Yes that's why I'm asking this question. Please see the link above.